# Concerned about future visa applications with an entry refusal on an old passport

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

I was once refused entry to Russia and this got stamped on one of my old passports. Assuming that I now apply for a Schengen visa, will:

1. They ask to attach my old passports?
2. If yes, will such an entry refusal affects the result of my Schengen visa application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The application will ask you whether you've ever been refused entry to a country - you should of course answer that fully and truthfully. Schengen applications are considered as a whole, with many factors involved. If your application is otherwise solid, the Russian entry refusal will probably not be an issue. The most important thing is to make sure your Schengen visa application is complete and satisfactory.

Comment: Yeah, that's for sure. However, I haven't noticed this question before in the classical Schengen application...

Answer (score 1):

A rejection stamp from *anywhere* in your passport might well cause a consular officer to spend a few extra minutes on making sure everything is in order. But it is not itself a ground for refusal, nor does it mean you application has to pass any stricter conditions than it ordinarily would.

So unless your application *depends on* something escaping the consular officer's notice, there should not be a problem.

The Russian government is not exactly widely respected in Europe for its spotless approach to human rights. There are plenty of ways to become unpopular with it that EU countries have no interest at all in helping "punish", even at the best of times. And now is not, diplomatically speaking, the best of times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see your point. How about my 1st question? As part of the Schengen application, do they ask to submit old original passports as well?